Drizzle orm self referening table and relation names
I have a categories model that can have many subcategories that self-reference the categories model.
export const categories = pgTable("categories", {
  id: text("id").primaryKey(),
  name: text("name").notNull(),
  userId: text("user_id").notNull(),
  parentCategoryId: text("parent_category_id").references(
    (): AnyPgColumn => categories.id
  ),
});

export const categoriesRelations = relations(
  categories,
  ({ many, one }) => ({
    transactions: many(transactions),
    savedCategories: many(savedCategories),
    subCategories: many(categories, {
      relationName: "subCategories",
    }),
    parentCategory: one(categories, {
      fields: [categories.parentCategoryId],
      references: [categories.id],
      relationName: "parent_category",
    }),
  })
);

I am getting the following error when trying to run dirzzle studio:

Error: There is not enough information to infer relation "public.categories.subCategories"
at normalizeRelation

My research says that I need to have {relationName: ...} on both sides of the relation, but it is self-referencing.

l find solution. You only need give same relationName subCategories and parentCategory. example:
export const categoriesRelations = relations(
  categories,
  ({ many, one }) => ({
    transactions: many(transactions),
    savedCategories: many(savedCategories),
    subCategories: many(categories, {
      relationName: "subCategories",
    }),
    parentCategory: one(categories, {
      fields: [categories.parentCategoryId],
      references: [categories.id],
      relationName: "subCategories",
    }),
  })
);

